# Split posts between databases

Tags: database

My client requested quite a specific solution for his WP based wordpress (single site, not multisite).
Basically what he wants is, let's say after 1000 posts new database should be created (with 5 tables only, posts, postmeta and 3 taxonomy related tables) and new posts should be stored in this one along with all post meta, until it reaches 1000 posts and then process repeats.

Challenging part is, all these databases have to be active at the same time, so WP should be able to access posts from main db and all these newly created databases (with 5 tables) at the same time. This could probably done with [hyperdb](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/). Questions are:

- How do I tell wp which database to save posts to?
- Is this even doable to begin with?
- If so, can it be done without modifications to WP core?

Comment: The real question here is, why? And, does it really make sense to do it this way? Or is there a better solution to achieve the why.

Answer (score 0):

It is not doable if you want to keep around **all** wordpress features. Possible casualties of such configuration are search and RSS feeds, probably also category and author pages.

If you go and actually create a new DB for each 1k posts then the game ends here as there is no simple way to share data between different databases. If you just want to create new tables every 1k posts then it will like multi site feature that require searching over the whole network, not elegant but possible.

As for the explicit points

1. it is harder because of the artifcial number limit. Most schemes which distribute data between DBs that I know are based on some hashing of the url, but that reuires to have all the DBs setup from day 1 and not waiting to fill a quota before creting the next DB.
2. It is if the owner of the site agrees to crippled functionally. For example it might be ok for a site which has only landing pages.
3. yes, can be done but you might need to overide the db.php file